# World Background Solid Colour Cycles

Tags: node-editor, world

I'm new to blender, and would not consider myself to be 'good' at it. I'm trying to create a changeable sky texture that I can use for an animation by changing the world colours using sky nodes and noise nodes. But when I do so, the colour remains solid.[image: Nodes should work, but colour remains solid]

[image]

Comment: maybe because you are in orthographic mode. press numpad-5

Comment: Fun fact, the reason only one pixel is visible of the world background in orthographic view is because the camera is simulating parallel rays. Thus, no matter where one  points the camera, only the rays parallel to the direction of the camera will reach it. Because the world background is essentially a sphere, that means only two points will have a normal that is parallel to the camera-- the one directly in front of the lens and the one behind the lens (thus would not be visible!)

Comment: As @DiogoValadares said, if you are trying to use a sky texture or HDR image, you will need to be in perspective view to see it. Otherwise it will display as the color of the single pixel that is directly opposite your view.

Answer (score 2):

You are in orthographic view, press 5 on your numpad.

Comment: It's telling me not to say thanks, but I do appreciate a good answer to a dumb question, so thank you.